# Simulating events on UIElement's without inheriting on Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

I have a very simple requirement, i.e. I want to send a synthetic event to a UIElement, in this case, a Grid. What I want is simply that I be able to send a synthetic event to an UIElement.

For example,

```
StackPanel myPanel;
StackPanel topPanel;

topPanel.MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(topPanel_MouseLeftButtonUp);

private void topPanel_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs args) {
    // Here I want to send the MouseLeftButtonUp event to myPanel
}
```

It is possible using `RaiseEvent`, but it is a protected event and hence I cannot just call it on an instance of any UIElement. So how do I go about sending a synthetic event on existing classes?

P.S: The reason that I cannot create custom inherited classes is that the current code base is too huge and the number of changes that will be required in case I take such an approach are not feasible.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Regards,
roahn

Answer (score 0):

Instead of raising events, you could just move the relevant code from the event handler to a method. Then, you can just call the method whenever you want to simulate a button click. However, if you want to simulate the button click on an element, you could do this:

```
//Assuming myPanel_MouseLeftButtonUp is the event handler for myPanel
myPanel_MouseLeftButtonUp(null, null);
```

Comment: The problem is that I cannot just call the event handler, because I am relying on the fact that an event on the StackPanel bubbles to the other UIElements the StackPanel contains, and it is their event handlers I am concerned about. Plus, those objects are generated on the fly, and hence rely on the 'sender' property which is set depending on which of the StackPanel's children exactly was clicked.