# No ContentControl.RaiseEvent in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

NOTE: This question is (in part) related to: [Simulating events on UIElement's without inheriting on Windows Phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641220/)

I have made a custom user control using this:

```
public class MyClass : ContentControl {
    public void SomeMethod() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

But I am not able to call the RaiseEvent method of ContentControl. IIRC, ContentControl inherits from `UIElement`, but why do I get the error saying that `RaiseEvent` is not defined in this context?

I'm using Silverlight (Windows Phone 7), so is it an issue due to that, since it is a subset of WPF and I've been dealing with a lot of lack of functionality in Silverlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a list of UIElement members in Silverlight:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement(v=VS.95).aspx

and this one members in WPF (.net 4.0)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement(v=VS.100).aspx

Apparently this method is not included in Silverlight (and WP7).